# Laravel get one record from the database

Tags: laravel

Im trying to make a list with game developers, and when you click on one of them you can see the games they have made. I only dont know how to get further....

This is what i have now:

**Index.blade.php:**

```
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col">Naam</th>
    <th scope="col">Opgericht in:</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($gamedevs as $gamedev)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $gamedev['id'] }} </td>
    <td><a href="">{{ $gamedev['naam'] }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ $gamedev['opgericht'] }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

I already tried some methods like these:

```
href="{{route('games.show', ['id'=>$gamedev->id])}}
```

and

```
href="/games/{{$gamedev['id']}}
```

**listcontroller.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $gamedevs = Gamedevs::all();

        return view("index", [ 'gamedevs' => $gamedevs]);

    }


public function show(Gamedevs $gamedevs)
{
    $gamedevs = Gamedevs::where($gamedevs)->first();

    return view('pages.games.show')->with('Gamedevs',$gamedevs);
}
```

Never did this before.. so hope im on the right way :)

Comment: What is your question? is your code working and you're asking if it is the right way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel controller methods like `show` will use [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container) to resolve all the parameters you define there. Since you define a model, laravel will automatically find the one corresponding with [explicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#explicit-binding).

So you wont have to write another query to show your Gamedev:

```php
public function show(Gamedevs $gamedevs)
{
    return view('pages.games.show')->with('Gamedevs',$gamedevs);
}
```

Comment: oke thanks! but how i can call the record with a Href in index.blade? When u now click on the href i get a 404 error, but in the url I do get the id of the record: http://127.0.0.1:8000/games/1

Comment: Did you add the route in `routes/web.php`?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem... I had a type, oops. Hope I can now go further Thanks John!

Answer (score 0):

Sample route in web.php

Route::get('/games/{dev_id}','listController@show');

Sample Method in your listController.php

public function show($gamedevs)

{

#let's say your $gamedevs is your devs id so target their id's

```
$devs = Gamedevs::where('id',$gamedevs)->first();

return view('pages.games.show')->with([
  'Gamedevs'=>$devs
]);
```

}

In your view

href="/games/{{$Gamedevs->id}}